# iOS: receive just an info when a new notification arrives in the notification center (swiping from top down the screen)

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications

Is it possible to just get an information when a new notification arrives in the notification center which is not pushed for my app but a notification for the user? I don't want to know what is inside the notification but only get an info if one arrives. Any ideas?

I'm looking for a solution without using APNS/& Bluetooth Devices.

Thanks for your help! :)

EDIT: i'm looking quite a long time now for a solution, did read much about distributed notifications, APNS, iOS system log files and so forth but didn't find that peace of code which is the magical solution.

EDIT 2: seems to only work with additional bluetooth environment. Doesn't help me in finding a solution so if anyone still has an idea, feel free to join this topic :)

Comment: No, it isn't possible.

Comment: so the only way would be to use bluetooth peripherals to get access to all the received notifications? Isn't there some sort of log file in which a new notification is documented? There has to be a solution without peripherals connected to the iOS device...would be bad if not :-/ :-)

Comment: No, it would be bad if it was - It would be a potential security risk and violation of the user's privacy

Comment: at first, thanks for the answer.but when i build a customized bluetooth dongle or use a bluetooth peripheral apple grants me to get access to all notifications and doesn't see that as a security violation. (see: http://appleinsider.com/articles/13/06/13/bluetooth-devices-to-gain-notification-support-in-ios-7-mavericks-with-apples-new-apis)

Comment: Correct, because the user pairs the device with their phone and this implies that they (not Apple) have granted permission for the device to access their notifications.  Without pairing the device cannot access any information.

Comment: that sounds logical to me. so i have to make a suggestion to apple to implement these features also w/o having to use bt devices, for example when granted by the user through approving a question when the app launches for example.

Comment: You can request it but I wouldn't hold your breath.